# How to do that all browsers have the same font?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

How to do that all browsers have the same font?

I have one page problem with fonts because on browsers like Internet Explorer Edge and 11 , Chrome or Firefox I have good font which I want but Internet Explorer 8 I have font which is wrong. So how to make that Internet Explorer 8 has the same font as the other?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate all formats of fonts from here
https://www.web-font-generator.com/
It might help you